# suggestion in visual studio code doesn't work in python define function

Tags: python, string, visual-studio-code, methods, intellisense

I'm programming in python

[image: example]

I'm making a function in Python using Visual Studio Code but the suggestions don't include string methods like `replace()`, `lower()` and `strip()`.

I don't know what is causing this issue and I tried every setting in Visual Studio Code. Can anyone tell me why it doesn't show the methods while other IDEs do?

Comment: What other IDEs are you referring to that give you better results for Python?

Comment: if you don't give a type hint that `text` is a string you don't get suggestions

Comment: why do you have a squiggle under `def` and at the end of the print function

Comment: why don't  you do a search for `python type hint`, VSC uses a static code analyzer

Comment: you are now treating me as if I make a question and you need to explain it to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `text:str` so that pylance knows text is String.

Your original code doesn't define the type of `text`. It can be any type. Naturally, pylance can't give advice.

[image]